# VueJs Router set config to support hash with no slash

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I need to use hash router. But the route must not contain slash after /# as shown below.

/#/user/test/ => /#user/test/

In react router, it was easy just use noSlash prop. But, I don't know how can I do it with VueJS.